# What is the homeomorphism type of the surface given by the polygonal presentation $aaa$?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

More precisely, I am interested in the mapping cone of the map $S^1 \to S^1,$ $z \mapsto z^3.$ It seems like it should yield a "surface" with the following polygonal presentation:
[image: presentation]

What is this space, exactly?

Comment: It's not a surface: any neighborhood of the arrowhead looks like three sheets of paper attached along their sides, in other words, the space isn't locally homeomorphic to $\Bbb R^2$.

Comment: You should take a look at W.S. Massey's book *Algebraic Topology: An Introduction*; he briefly discusses this space as a cautionary tale about inferring too much about quotients $X/f$ from $X$.

Comment: @Eppo Would you mind telling me at what page or chapter he discusses this space? I have the book with me but I can't seem to find the part you are referencing.

Comment: @IAmFailure I seem to have misremembered.  This is actually an exercise from W.S. Massey *A Basic Course in Algebraic Topology*, page 206.  I believe that the space is called the "Dunce Cap."  I hope this helps.

Comment: Is this the 3-fold dunce cap?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is this space, exactly?

The cone $X = Cf$ is the quotient space $Mf/X\times\{0\}$ obtained from pinching the top of the mapping cylinder to a point. Since $Mf$ is the cylinder $S^1 \times [0, 1]$ with the bottom pasted to $S^1$ by $f$, $Cf$ is the $2$-dimensional cell complex $D^2 \cup_f S^1$.

This is formally called the $3$-fold dunce cap, and the fundamental polygon you depicted is indeed correct. It's a generalization of the projective space $\Bbb RP^2$ in the sense that mapping cone of the two fold covering map $f : S^1 \to S^1$ is $\Bbb RP^2$.

$\pi_1(X) = \langle a | a^3 = 1\rangle \cong \Bbb Z/3$ as the loops given by the words $1, a, a^2$ at the boundary of the cap are all distinct, and $a^3$ can be homotoped to a point by sliding through the interior of the disk.

However, as noted by Olivier Bégassat in the comments, $X$ is not a $2$-manifold : any open neighborhood of a point lying on the boundary of the triangle $aaa$ is homeomorphic to three half-disks pasted by the diameter, which is not homeomorphic to $\Bbb R^2$.

Comment: Thank you. Would you mind looking at my computation of the homology of this space below? I am not sure the computation of $H_2$ is entirely correct.

Answer (score 0):

Is the following computation of $H_*(X)$ correct?

Since $X$ is a $2$-dimensional cell complex, $H_n(X) = 0$ for $n \geq 3.$

Taking $A = $ the boundary circle of the fundamental polygon, the long exact sequence of a pair yields $$0 = H_2(A) \to H_2(X) \to H_2(X,A) \to H_1(A) \cong \mathbb{Z};$$ I believe $(X,A)$ is a good pair, so that $H_2(X,A) \cong H_2(X/A) \cong H_2(S^2) \cong \mathbb{Z}.$ I believe that the fundamental polygon, viewed as a relative 2-cycle, generates $H_2(X,A),$ and is mapped to the generator of  $H_1(A)$ under the boundary map. Hence the rightmost arrow is injective, which implies that $H_2(X) = 0.$

Finally, $H_1(X) = \pi_1(X) = \mathbb{Z}/3$ and $H_0(X) = \mathbb{Z}.$

Comment: Yes, your proof looks good. $(X, A)$ is indeed a good pair, since CW-pairs has homotopy extension property and the map you mentioned is indeed injective, since $H_2(X, A)$ is generated by the fundamental polygon and, geometrically, is sent to the boundary, i.e., the generator of $A$ given by looping around it once by the boundary map in the long exact sequence.

Comment: Thank you so much, @BalarkaSen! You've been immensely helpful. I greatly appreciate your feedback!

Comment: Happy to help. ${}$

Comment: @BalarkaSen I just thought of a related question. If instead of $aaa$ the given word representing the fundamental polygon was $aaa^{-1},$ would be it possible to represent the resulting space as a cell complex? If so, what would be the attaching map $f:S^1 \to S^1$ look like in that case?

Comment: Well, you have an obvious cell complex structure $D^2 \cup_f S^1$ given by the word $aaa^{-1}$. However, the attaching map can be homotoped to the identity map as $a(aa^{-1}) \sim a$, so the resulting space is just a disk, which is contractible.

Comment: @BalarkaSen I'm a bit confused. In the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunce_hat_%28topology%29) for the dunce hat, and also in an exercise in Bredon, the fundamental polygon for what they call the dunce hat is $aaa^{-1}.$ Certainly that space isn't homeomorphic to a disc? Also, I meant to ask if we can find a nice expression for a map $f:S^1 \to S^1$ (like $z \mapsto z^3$ above) whose mapping cone yields that "version" of the dunce hat.

Comment: Yes, several people call $D \cup_{aaa^{-1}} S^1$ the dunce hat/cap instead, but Munkres calls the $D \cup_{aaa} S^1$ version dunce cap. The former is homotopy equivalent to the disk (i.e., contractible), the latter isn't. For your second question, consider the map $f : S^1 \to S^1$ which maps one-third of your domain circle to all of the codomain circle by joining the ends, the next one-third to the same thing, and the rest of it by composing with the antipodal map. You should be able to write down a piece-wise continuous function corresponding to the word $aaa^{-1}$ now.

Comment: @BalarkaSen Ah, you meant up to homotopy. Your $f$ also makes a lot of sense. Thank you very much for your extended help.