# Show that there are exactly two spaces obtained from identifying edges of a triangle.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, triangles, homology-cohomology, fundamental-groups

I think I can visualize one of them, which would be identifying two edges together to get a cone. Would the other one be identifying all three edges together for a disk? I have a harder time actually writing up a proof for stuff like this.

What would their fundamental groups or singular homology groups look like?

Comment: Once you pick two edges to identify, you have two options: do you identify the points that already coincide, or do you switch the orientation for one edge?

Comment: In other words, if the original triangle has vertices $(0,0), (0,1)$ and $(1,0)$, do we put $(x,0)\sim (0,x)$, or $(x,0)\sim(0,1-x)$?

Comment: I think your question may be asking you to identify every edge with another edge: so the two spaces will be Zeeman's [dunce hat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunce_hat_(topology)) and one other

Comment: Any idea on what the other space is?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1279263/what-is-the-homeomorphism-type-of-the-surface-given-by-the-polygonal-presentatio